# ImageSharp.Web with AzureBlobStorageImageProvider giving 404's

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, imagesharp

Following the example code I'm attempting to hook up an ImageSharp.Web's `AzureBlobStorageImageProvider` but all image requests result in 404's. Any idea what I'm missing from my wiring-up?

Looking at the docs it seems the url convention should be https://localhost:44336/container-name/file-name.jpg?width=30

In my Startup.cs I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddImageSharp()
        .Configure<AzureBlobStorageImageProviderOptions>(options =>
        {
            // The "BlobContainers" collection allows registration of multiple containers.
            options.BlobContainers.Add(new AzureBlobContainerClientOptions
            {
                ConnectionString = "REDACTED",
                ContainerName = "test-container"
            });
        })
        .AddProvider<AzureBlobStorageImageProvider>()
        .Configure<AzureBlobStorageCacheOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = "REDACTED";
            options.ContainerName = "cache";

            // Optionally create the cache container on startup if not already created.
            AzureBlobStorageCache.CreateIfNotExists(options, PublicAccessType.None);
        })
        .SetCache<AzureBlobStorageCache>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseImageSharp();
}
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to `ClearProviders()` first before adding the `AzureBlobStorageImageProvider`. So the code becomes:

```
.ClearProviders()
.AddProvider<AzureBlobStorageImageProvider>()
```

Comment: Yep the providers are loaded in order so the local file provider (which is a capture all provider) needs to follow any more specific ones.